# How do I share a file to a specific folder using Google Drive API?

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api, drive

I did the code below and I tried to use 'parents' to share a file to a specific folder, but it didn't work. I looked everywhere for a solution, but I can't find any.

```
function grantPermission($role, $user, $atividade){
    $userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
        'type' => 'user',
        'role' => $role,
        'emailAddress' => $user->email,
        'parents' => array($user->folder_id_minhas_atividades),
    ));

    $request = $this->drive->permissions->create($atividade->folder_id, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
    
    $ret = redirect()->route('verAtividade.verPessoas', ['atividade_id' => $atividade->id]);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: The file always goes to Shared with me, but what I want to is to share a file and this file has to go to the user folder ($user->folder_id_minhas_atividades).

Comment: Are you wanting to move a file from "Shared with me" to "My Drive" using the API?

Comment: Do you want to place the shared file into a specific folder in your Drive, another user"s Drive or a shared Drive? Is the user with whom you want to share from your domain?

Comment: To a specific folder in another user's Drive, supposing that I have the information of the folder_id and permission of the user @JM-AGMS

Comment: To a specific folder in another user's Drive, supposing that I have the information of the folder_id and permission of the user @ziganotschka

Comment: Having permission of the user means that you have edit access to his folder?

Comment: Yes, in this application that I'm working on, the user logs in the system with the google account e then the user gives permission to write and read his/her google drive @ziganotschka

Answer (score 0):

### If you share a file with a user, this file will remain in your Drive

The user will only see it as "Shared with me", but not in a folder on his Drive.

For what you are trying to achieve you need to update the parents of the file instead of changing the permissions.

Provided you move the file to a folder on a user's Drive - the user will automatically obtain access permissions for the file.

**Use the method [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) and pass to the parameter `addParents` the folder id.**

Sample:

```php
$driveService = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
$file = $driveService->files->update($fileId, $emptyFileMetadata, array(
    'addParents' => $folderId
));
```

Depending on the situation you might also need to specify in the request body `'removeParents' => $previousParents`.